# How to check Azure blob storage path exists or not using scala spark or python spark

Tags: scala, azure, pyspark, blob, azure-blob-storage

Please let me know how to check below blob file exists or not.

file path name : "wasbs://containername@storageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/directoryname/meta_loaddate=20190512/"

Comment: Was the provided answer helpful for you? If so, please mark as answered to help the community find relevant answers.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a code that would work for you, feel to free to edit/customize per your needs:

```
  from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService

session = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate() #setup spark session
    session.conf.set("fs.azure.account.key.storage-account-name.blob.core.windows.net","<storage-account-key>")
    sdf = session.read.parquet("wasbs://<container-name>@<storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/<prefix>")

    block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name='', account_key='')

    def blob_exists():

            container_name = ""
            blob_name = ""

            exists=(block_blob_service.exists(container_name, blob_name))
            return exists
    blobstat = blob_exists()
    print(blobstat)# will return a boolean if the blob exists = True, else False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private val storageConnectionString = s"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=$account;AccountKey=$accessKey"

private val cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString)

private val serviceClient = cloudStorageAccount.createCloudBlobClient

private val container = serviceClient.getContainerReference("data")

val ref = container.getBlockBlobReference(path)
val existOrNot = ref.exist()
```